# How to set the heat transfer coefficient of condenser steam side in Thermal Power Library？

Tags: modelica, dymola

I know that few people use Dymola's commercial library thermal power, but I ask a detailed question with a try attitude. If anyone understands and answers, thank you very much.

Question: how to set the steam side heat transfer coefficient of condenser assembly (divided into three condensation sections) in thermal power to ensure that it will meet different application environments as much as possible. I know this is an empirical value, but I still want to find some basis.

[image]
[image]

Finally, I just contacted this community (but it doesn't mean I didn't retrieve relevant questions), so I don't ask standardized questions. I hope to get understanding. Thank you.

Comment: This library is from Modelon (not Dymola resp. Dassault Systemes). Have you tried to contact their support: https://www.modelon.com/support-learning/ ?

Comment: You can find typical values and reasonable range for example in this publication: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-77877-6_6